# UINavigation Bar Button Item next to Back

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uinavigationitem, uinavigationcontroller

I currently have a view which segues to a UINavigation View on a button click. It works great with one additional view after the first segue but I'd like to add more views as you progress after the first view.

Once you reach the last view, the Navigation Bar only has `< Back` but I'd like to include a `Bar Button Item` on that view so that I can traverse to another view rather than creating another Navigation Controller. Is there any way to do this?

**Here are some screenshots to help illustrate:**

Here is the first view you segue to.

[image: First view]

//

Here is the second view you segue to with my own `Bar Button Item`

[image: Second view]

//

And finally the last view with `< Back` that is automatically added by UINavigation but what if I wanted to progress to another view after this? How would I include a `Bar Button Item` here?

[image: Last view]

And the Storyboard:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Bar Button Item` available in the Object Library.

[image]

As the description says, it behaves similarly like a button. Add this to your navigation and then control-drag this to the viewcontroller/nagivationview you want to transition to and create a segue.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add UIBarButtonItem programatically on left or right side of Navigationbar.

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
 UIBarButtonItem *button=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ButtonAction)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
```

Handle Button Tap Action

```
-(void)ButtonAction{
  }
```

You can also add button to right side by using rightBarButtonItem .
Hope it helps..